# How would you alert a fellow member a link is broken without commenters status?

Tags: discussion

I have discovered a link in a users answer, where the link is directed to a website that is no longer available. How would you indicate that link as broken without the ability to leave a comment?

Comment: You're not at all far from the magic 50 points, after which you can comment freely.

Comment: you can now! you can now! comment! feel tha paawor!

Comment: xD *does the irish jig*

Answer (score 19):

In this order:

- Fix it, if you can. You can't comment but you can edit...
  But just fix the link, don't add commentary to their post.
- Find somebody in [General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) who can leave a comment
- And if the whole answer hinges on that link working, flag it for a mod (or improve it, if you can).

Comment: Not sure about the order, but definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

So long as the question or answer does not already have a pending suggested edit, and the question is not on a meta site, you can include a link to an archived copy of the document in a suggested edit to the question or answer.

1. Copy the linked URL.
2. Visit the [Internet Archive](https://www.archive.org/).
3. In the "Wayback Machine" section, paste the URL into the input field and activate the "Browse History" button.
4. Try snapshots of the document until you find an appropriate one.
5. Copy the URL.
6. Edit the question or answer and paste in the archived URL.

Once you have fixed broken links this way in 25 different posts, you should qualify for commenting privileges.